# rsync remote site with bash

Tags: linux, macos, bash, ftp, rsync

Hope you can advise I want to use rsync to carry out my FTP transactions but with bash.

How can I add the password to the rsync command.

I have for example.

```
rsync -r -update user@domain.com:/public_html/ /var/www/domin.com/public_html
```

Hope you can advise.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Its ok to use ssh keys if you have ssh access on cliient server but thats not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer would be to use ssh keys

[This site](http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/index.html) provides a guide on creating and using ssh keys with rsync:

Comment: Is rsync required on the other machine? (I hope not)

Comment: @trusktr - yes, but most Unix systems have rsyncd

Comment: Oooh, ok. Well on my system, if I SSH in and try the rsync command it says command not found, but it also says the same thing for the ftp command, although I can still FTP in with an FTP client. Will it still work then if rsyncd is running but the command is not available for me via SSH?

Answer (score 1):

From `man rsync`:

> Some  modules  on  the  remote  daemon
>   may require authentication. If so, you
>   will receive a password prompt when
>   you connect. You can avoid the
>   password  prompt  by setting the
>   environment variable RSYNC_PASSWORD to
>   the password you want to use or using
>   the --password-file option. This may
>   be useful when scripting rsync.

Comment: Ive just seen the -password-file option. How what were would i add it ??

Comment: You just add --password-file=mypassword.txt to your rsync command-line, and make sure the file mypassword.txt contains the password in question. Make sure mypassword.txt is only readable to you. If you care about security, using ssh keys (as other have mentioned) would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty good howto on setting up rsync with ssh using the authorized keys feature of ssh.   http://blogs.oracle.com/jkini/entry/how_to_scp_scp_and

SSH is encrypted and the keys are much more secure than rsh authentication or using password files.

Answer (score 0):

According to serverfault you can't, but there are some alternatives: https://serverfault.com/questions/24622/how-to-use-rsync-over-ftp